# Pyomo: How to use the final data point in an abstract model's objective?

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I have a Pyomo model which has the form:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.dae import *

m      = AbstractModel()
m.t    = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0,120)) 
m.T    = Param(default=120)
m.S    = Var(m.t, bounds=(0,None))
m.Sdot = DerivativeVar(m.S)
m.obj  = Objective(expr=m.S[120],sense=maximize)
```

Note that the objective `m.obj` relies on the parameter `m.T`. Attempting to run this gives the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'SimpleParam'
```

Using a value, such as `expr=m.S[120]` gives the error:

```
ValueError: Error retrieving component S[120]: The component has not been constructed.
```

In both cases, my goal is the same: to optimize for the largest possible value of `S` at the horizon.

How can I create an abstract model which expresses this?

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting on two somewhat separate issues:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'SimpleParam'
```

Is due to a bug in Pyomo 4.3 where you cannot directly use simple `Param`s as indexes into other components.  That said, the fix for this particular problem will not fix your example model.

The trick to fixing your `Objective` declaration is to encapsulate the `Objective` expression within a rule:

```
def obj_rule(m):
    return m.S[120]
    # or better yet:
    #   return m.S[m.T]
    # or 
    #   return m.S[m.t.last()]
m.obj  = Objective(rule=obj_rule,sense=maximize)
```

The problem is that when you are writing an Abstract model, each component is only being *declared*, but not *defined*.  So, the Var `S` is declared to exist, but has not been defined (it is an empty shell with no members).  This causes a problem because Python (not Pyomo) attempts to resolve the `m.S[120]` to a specific variable immediately before calling the `Objective` constructor.  The use of rules (functions) in Abstract models allows you to defer the resolution of the expression until Pyomo is actually constructing the model instance.  Pyomo constructs the instance components in the same order that you declared them on the Abstract model, so when it fires the `obj_rule`, the previous components (`S`, `T`, and `t`) are all constructed and `S` has valid members at the known points of the `ContinuousSet` (in this case, the bounds).